# Django cannot get Django user model to work with send_mail

Tags: django, django-users

This line in the view breaks:

```
email = User.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('email', flat=True)
send_mail('subject', 'message','info@site.com', [email[0]])
```

Here is the error:

```
During handling of the above exception (Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: email, first_name, last_name, username), another exception occurred:
```

This used to work, but has now broken and have no idea why. The user has been created. This is the base Django model.

Comment: You can get email value directly from request.user object: request.user.email

Answer (score 0):

What causing the error in your code is that there is no `user` field on `User` so when trying to filter on that field, Django throws and exception.

To fix that line, you'd need to get the `id` of the user through the `request` object and filter on that

```py
email = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).values_list('email', flat=True)
```

However, this is unnecessary as it will just return a queryset containing the same user object as the `request`. You should just get the email field directly through the request and not perform the extra query.

```py
send_mail('subject', 'message','info@site.com', [request.user.email])
```